# ZF2 namespace for flashmessenger

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, flash-message

In my application I am using multiple forms, the forms submission points to another
action but redirects back to the previous action. In the form submission action I handle
the form input / validation. To return an error or success message I use the FlashMessenger.

My point of problem is that it's not clear how I set a namespace for the FlashMessenger. I have serval forms on the same page where I would like to use FlashMessenger messenges.

```
    if ($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()) {

      $messages = $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages();
      foreach($messages as $message) {
      echo $message;
      }

    }
```

I am guessing I should do something with '$this->flashMessenger('namespace').. In my controller action? But I didn't figure out how exactly make this work. If anyone has an example.. that would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace of the flash messenger controller plugin can be manual set using the `setNamespace($namespace)` method.

```
$this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('foo')->addMessage($message);
```

However there are also [convenience functions that will set a different namespace and message at the same time](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/Plugin/FlashMessenger.php#L202).

For example, if you want to add a success message then you can use:

```
$this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage($message);
```

Internally the plugin will set the namespace as `success` and add the message to it (and   then reset the namespace to allow for the next message to be set (defaults to `default`))

```
public function addSuccessMessage($message)
{
    $namespace = $this->getNamespace();
    $this->setNamespace(self::NAMESPACE_SUCCESS);
    $this->addMessage($message);
    $this->setNamespace($namespace);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Great explanation, Alex.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a message into a particular namespace by using these built-in methods in your action controller:

```
// in your controller
$this->flashMessenger()->addInfoMessage('info message');
$this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('success message');
$this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('error message');

// in your view script
$this->flashMessenger()->getInfoMessages();
$this->flashMessenger()->getSuccessMessages();
$this->flashMessenger()->getErrorMessages();
```

Or if you want to specify your own namespace, you can use something like:

```
// in your action controller
$defaultNamespace = $this->getNamespace();
$this->setNamespace('yournamespace');
$this->addMessage($message);
$this->setNamespace($defaultNamespace);

// in your view script
$this->flashMessenger()->getMessagesFromNamespace('yournamespace');
```

For more information, you can see the documentation:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#flashmessenger-plugin
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.flash-messenger.html#basic-usage